# Custom .ToString() Formats in .rdlc Reports

Tags: .net, vb.net, rdlc, tostring

I have a custom business object which overloads the .ToString() function. It also implements IFormattable.ToString, so I can define my own custom formats.

This approach seems to work everywhere in my app, except .rdlc reports. For example, I have a text field on a report with the following expression:

```
=Fields!MyField.Value.ToString("lr")
```

"lr" is a custom format I have created. When running the report I always get #Error as the output. I've placed breakpoints in my .ToString function and stepped through the code as the report is running, and I know the function is returning the correct value, but the report just doesn't seem to be capable of receiving and displaying it.

Comment: Have you tried `Fields("MyField").Value.ToString("lr")`? Does it yield the same result (it should)?

Comment: No luck unfortunately. In fact the more I look at this, the more it seems that passing a parameter to a function in an rdlc textbox isn't possible. Calling .ToString() seems to work, but calling .ToString("lr") produces #Error. Can anyone confirm if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to do in a different way in the rdlc report you can use VB code. Just click on the report with right mouse button. When the context menu from where you enter parameters go to Proprties. When clicking it you should see a tab control witch few tab pages. Go to tab page "Code" an there right you VB function it must be something like this

```
 Public Function ParseVal(ByVal val As Object ) As String
     Dim MyClass As obj = CType(val, MyClass )
     return obj.ToString( "lr" ) 
    End Function
```

Then call the function in your textbox like this

```
= Code.ParseVal(Fields!MyField.Value )
```

P.S. I am not very sure if the VB code is working correctly just test it and if it is needed rewrite. If any other error occurs please post it to see what is the problem