# Custom Format in RDLC

Tags: report, reporting, rdlc

I have a challenge in RDLC Report, to get amount in custom Format. e.g

```
150 will be shown as 15A
151 will be like 15B
152 will be like 15C etc.
```

Last digit in amount will be replaced will A,B,C etc. `From 0 to 9 will be replace with A to J`

Is there any custom format available, or some function to be written for such format?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about this will work for you, yes but have some logic for your answer.

You have to use your custom logic ([I think vb code is acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359927/how-to-write-custom-code-in-rdlc-report)) here as you code in c#. you define a parameter and code it, that will return as you want.

http://yuluer.com/page/ddcjfdcd-rdlc-report-in-space.shtml

[Custom .ToString() Formats in .rdlc Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362185/custom-tostring-formats-in-rdlc-reports)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms252130%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

[How to replace a particular string in rdlc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390259/how-to-replace-a-particular-string-in-rdlc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
=Left(CStr(Fields!YourNumber.Value), CStr(Fields!YourNumber.Value).Length - 1) &
Choose(Right(CStr(Fields!YourNumber.Value), 1), "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
```

Use [Choose function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/824bz7dy(v=vs.90).aspx) to substitute the last digit in your number.